# A confusion of a real analysis online lecture: Relative compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkKfRaI-cqs

At 13.00 what does the professor mean to let those subcovers be "restricted" to Y?
Is that a process like
A is contained by B implies that A intersect C in contained by B intersect C?
Isn't it a lemma that needs to be proved?

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space, then the subspace topology on $Y\subseteq X$ is defined as the intersection of $Y$ with all of the open subsets of $X$. Every open set in $Y$ is the intersection of some open set in $X$ with $Y$. "Restriction" isn't the best word to use in this context; intersection makes more sense.

Comment: @T.A.E.: You’re not intersecting the cover with $Y$, but rather its elements, so *intersection* isn’t really a good choice. In fact, the only two terms that I’ve at all commonly encountered for $\{U\cap Y:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$ are the *restriction* of $\mathscr{U}$ to $Y$ and the *trace* of $\mathscr{U}$ on $Y$.